# Is there a way to use data from a read file in VB as an active string variable?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a script that reads file data in a text file as a string then can be called as another variable. I've been working on it for a while.

Code that will open the file:

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso, BC1
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set BC1 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\GDoe\Desktop\BC1.txt",1)
MsgBox BC1.ReadLine
BC1.Close
```

I need to take the 1 line of data read from this textfile and set it as another variable in string format (ie: `Dim Variable1 As String = BC1 data`). Any ideas? If I can get the data I want from the file as a string, the rest of my script will execute like it should.

Comment: Dim reader As String
reader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt") This code let me do what I needed. If anyone knows another way for future reference I'd be interested but this worked for now. :)

Comment: The code in your comment isn't VBScript. Are you using VB.net?

Comment: You are correct. I thought the comment I posted solved my problem, however since I was editing using Visual Studio it accepted it but didn't correct it which gave me compilation errors when I tried to build without the platform. JosefZ below answered perfectly though since I got the whole code working again thanks to his help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save all file data in a text file to `strBC1` variable (string variant):

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso, BC1, strBC1
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set BC1 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\GDoe\Desktop\BC1.txt",1)
strBC1 = BC1.ReadAll
BC1.Close
```

To read a text file *line by line* and save 1st non-empty line to `strLine` variable (string variant):

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso, BC1, strLine
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set BC1 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\GDoe\Desktop\BC1.txt",1)
Do Until BC1.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = BC1.Readline
  If strLine <> "" Then
    Exit Do                  'stops looping and transfers control
                             ' to the statement immediately following the Loop 
  End If
Loop
BC1.Close
```

Comment: Thank you for the help JosefZ. Worked like a charm. :)